# Numeric comparisons with NA values causing bad subsets in R

Tags: r, comparison-operators, three-valued-logic

Can somebody explain to me why logical evaluations that resolve to NA produce bogus rows in vector-comparison-based subsets?  For example:

```
employee <- c("Big Shot CEO", "Programmer","Intern","Guy Who Got Fired Last Week")
salary <-   c(      10000000,        50000,       0,                           NA)
emp_salary <- data.frame(employee,salary)

# how many employees paid over 100K?
nrow(emp_salary[salary>100000,]) # Returns 2 instead of 1 -- why?

emp_salary[salary>100000,]
# returns a bogus row of all NA's (not "Guy Who Got Fired")
#        employee salary
# 1  Big Shot CEO  1e+07
# NA         <NA>   <NA>

salary[salary>100000]
# returns:
# [1] 1e+07    NA

NA > 100000 #returns NA
```

Given this unexpected behavior, what is the preferred way to count employees making over 100K in the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you probably don't want to `cbind()` first -- that will coerce all of your variables to character.

```
 emp_salary <- data.frame(employee,salary)
```

Two possible solutions:

- `subset` automatically excludes cases where the criterion is `NA`:

```
nrow(subset(emp_salary,salary>1e5))
```

- count the results directly and use `na.rm=TRUE`:

```
sum(salary>1e5,na.rm=TRUE)
```

As for the logic behind the bogus rows:

- `bigsal <- salary>1e5` is a logical vector which contains `NA`s, as it must (because there is no way to know whether an `NA` value satisfies the criterion or not).
- when indexing the rows of a data frame  with a logical vector containing `NA`s, this is probably the most salient bit of document (from `help("[")`):

> When extracting, a numerical, logical or character ‘NA’ index picks an unknown element and so returns ‘NA’ in the corresponding element of a logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result, and ‘NULL’ for a list.
>   
>   (I searched `help("[.data.frame")` and couldn't see anything more useful.)

The thing to remember is that once the indexing is being done, R no longer has any knowledge that the logical vector was created from the `salary` column, so there's no way for it to do what you might want, which is to retain the values in the other columns.  Here's one way to think about the seemingly strange behaviour of filling in all the columns in the `NA` row with `NA`s: if R leaves the row out entirely, that would correspond to the criterion being `FALSE`.  If it retains it (and remember that it can't retain just a few columns and drop the others), then that would correspond to the criterion being `TRUE`.  If the criterion is neither `FALSE` nor `TRUE`, then it's hard to see what other behaviour makes sense ...

Comment: Thanks, I edited the example to remove cbind, but it was getting un-coerced in the comparison anyway.  In my actual problem I had not used cbind, just merged two data sets.  Are you able to explain the problem with using the logical evaluation as an index?

Comment: Ah this makes sense (in an R sort of way).  Thank you.

Comment: FWIW I think it's not R's fault this time.  Any time you start trying to deal with the logic of `NA`s in a consistent way things are likely to get weird.

Comment: Great explanation of what things look like "from R's point of view".